# Completing an rectangular matrix in order to produce several square invertible well conditioned matrices

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

If I have a rectangular matrix `C`, with linear independent rows, (see information of its expected numerical values in the first observation at the bottom of the post), whose dimmension is `qxn` such that `q<=n` and I want to produce **several** square invertible matrix `T=[C;R]`.

An important point here is that the matrix T should be well conditioned (**condition number close to 1**).

I wrote a code that solves this problem in a very inneficient way:

```
 clear all
 C=[1 0]; %example
 tol=0.1;

 n=size(C,2);
 q=size(C,1);

 singularity=1;
 it=0;
 while(singularity==1)
    a=-5;
    b=5;
    R=a + (b - a) .* rand(n - q, n); %generates randomic R matrix with numerical values beetwen 'a' and 'b'
    M=[C;R];
    if(abs(cond(M)-1)<tol) %cond(M) computes the condition number of M
        singularity=0;
    end
    it=it+1;
end
```

Considering `C=[1 0]` the algorithm converges in a range of 700~2k iterations (however, the process runs very fast since the instructions are quite simple.)

Now, considering `C=[1 0 0]` I was forced to break the processing because the iterations were over than 2kkk.

**Observation**: The numerical of values of my matrix `C` usuaally will be small positive integers (from one to ten), small racional numbers from 0 to 5 and zeros.

**Important**: For one given matrix `C` I do **not** need just one matrix `R` that will make `M` well conditioned. In my application, I will need several matrix `R` (as many as I want) for one given `C`, so thats why I was trying to generate `R` randomic, but unfortunately in a very inefficient way.

**Remark**: Of course I can find one R such that M is well conditioned and then the other well conditioned matrices can be multiple of the previous one, but I wanna try other approaches.

Comment: Instead of nested for loop you can write `R = a + (b - a) .* rand(n - q, n);` to generate `R`

Comment: ok, now the code is simpler

Comment: and more efficient!

Comment: ok, but the main problem its in the effectiveness of the algorithm

Comment: you stated that you can find one R. Can you add small random numbers to each element of it instead of multiply it?.   `R2 = R +(rand(size(R))-.5)*.01;`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a qr decompositon of C' (C transpose) so that

```
C' = Q * ( R )
         ( 0 )
```

where R is qxq upper triangular and non-singular, and Q is orthogonal. Then for any non-singular (n-q)x(n-q) matrix B, and any q x (n-q) matrix A

```
Q * ( R A ) 
    ( 0 B )
```

will be non-singular and will have the same first q columns as C', so that the transpose of that is what you want.

For analysing the condition number I think it would be simplest to take A to be zero, for then we have

```
|| D || = || R || + || B || 
|| inv(D) || = || inv(R) || + || inv( B) ||
where
D = ( R 0 )
    ( 0 B )
```